# Non correct image filtering

Tags: c++, opencv, filtering, convolution

I have to create a function that filter an grey scale image in the frequency domain.
The main problem is that the result look like salt and pepper noise.

the main function is:

```
void FiltroFrequenze::dftMia(){
int rowsExtendedImage = image.rows + kernel.rows - 1;
int colsExtendedImage = image.cols + kernel.cols - 1;
Mat extendedImage(rowsExtendedImage, colsExtendedImage, image.type());
Mat extendedKernel(rowsExtendedImage, colsExtendedImage, image.type());
filtered=extendedImage.clone();

espansione(image,kernel,extendedImage);

Mat trasformata (rowsExtendedImage, colsExtendedImage, image.type());

translation(extendedImage,trasformata);


Mat planes[] ={Mat_<float>(trasformata),Mat::zeros(trasformata.size(),CV_32F)};
Mat complexI;
merge(planes,2,complexI);
dft(complexI,complexI);
cout<<"dft fatto"<<endl;
split(complexI,planes);

Mat magI=planes[0];


Mat moltiplicata(rowsExtendedImage, colsExtendedImage, image.type());

switch (type)
{
case 1:
    kernelPassaBasso(raggio);
    break;
case 2:
    kernelPassaAlto(raggio);
    break;
}
showImage(kernel,"kernel");
waitKey(0);
multiply(magI,kernel,moltiplicata);
//multiply(complexI,kernel,moltiplicata);

cout<<"moltiplicata"<<endl;

Mat inversa (rowsExtendedImage, colsExtendedImage, image.type());

dft(moltiplicata,inversa,DFT_INVERSE+DFT_SCALE);
split(inversa,planes);
    //magnitude(planes[0],planes[1],planes[0]);
     inversa=planes[0];
//inversa.convertTo(inversa,image.type());
cout<<"invertita"<<endl;
showImage(inversa,"inversa");
        waitKey(0);
translation(inversa,filtered);
//filtered.convertTo(filtered,image.type());
```

to translate the image in the frequency I use, in the spatial domain:

```
void FiltroFrequenze::translation(Mat image, Mat traslatedImage){
for(int x=0;x<image.rows;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<image.cols;y++)
    {


        if(image.channels()==1)
                {

                    traslatedImage.at<float>(x,y)=image.at<float>(x,y)*pow(-1,x+y);
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int k=0;k<image.channels();k++)
                    {
                        traslatedImage.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[k]=image.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[k]*pow(-1,x+y);
                    }
                }

    }
}
```

and to create the high pass and the low pass kernels:

```
void FiltroFrequenze::kernelPassaBasso(int raggio){
Mat kernelNew(kernel.rows+image.rows-1, kernel.cols+image.cols-1, CV_32FC1);
kernel=kernelNew;
drawCircle(kernel, raggio,  1.0, 0.0);
```

void FiltroFrequenze::kernelPassaAlto(int raggio){
    showImage(image,"immagine");

```
Mat kernelNew(kernel.rows+image.rows-1, kernel.cols+image.cols-1, CV_32FC1);
kernel=kernelNew.clone();
drawCircle(kernel, raggio,  0.0, 1.0);




void FiltroFrequenze::drawCircle(Mat image, int raggio, float colorCircle, float colorBackground){
int center[]={floor(kernel.rows/2)+1,floor(kernel.cols/2)+1};
for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
    {
        if(pow(x-center[1],2)+pow(y-center[0],2)<pow(raggio,2))
        {
            image.at<float>(y,x)=colorCircle;
        }
        else
        {
            image.at<float>(y,x)=colorBackground;
        }
    }
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is, that what you see is caused by the fact, that the image being the result of filtering gets cast to float. OpenCV displays float images correctly only when the floats are in the <0, 1> range, so you'll have to get your results back to 8-bit or scale properly.